# Ruby Date.parse and Javascript new Date() does not accept same formats

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery-ui

**Solution:**

I used the [american_date gem](https://github.com/jeremyevans/ruby-american_date) for the ruby end, and used this regex for js validation.

```
/^(?=\d)(?:(?:31(?!.(?:0?[2469]|11))|(?:30|29)(?!.0?2)|29(?=.0?2.(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00)))(?:\x20|$))|(?:2[0-8]|1\d|0?[1-9]))([-./])(?:1[012]|0?[1-9])\1(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d\d(?:(?=\x20\d)\x20|$))?(((0?[1-9]|1[012])(:[0-5]\d){0,2}(\x20[AP]M))|([01]\d|2[0-3])(:[0-5]\d){1,2})?$/.test(value)
```

**Question**

I am using jquery datepicker on date fields and they users are able to type the date.

I want the users in my application to be able to choose their own date format. they can choose either US format mm/dd/yy or European format dd.mm.yy.

I am using a javascript format validator. like this

```
!/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date(value).toString());
```

( I really like the idea of not using a regex )

Ruby and javascript is alas making this hard.

irb:

```
2.0.0p247 :018 > Date.parse("11/02/2013")
 => Mon, 11 Feb 2013
```

javascript console

```
new Date("11/02/2013")
Sat Nov 02 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)
```

irb:

```
2.0.0p247 :029 >   Date.parse("11.02.2013")
=> Mon, 11 Feb 2013
```

javascript console

```
new Date("11.02.2013")
Sat Nov 02 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)
```

If the validating passes I get a nil in the date field in the database, and
If the the date is ruby correct the validator does not pass.

I need an elegant solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at the gem [american_date](https://github.com/jeremyevans/ruby-american_date), it will allow ruby to take dates formated as MM/DD/YYYY and is as simple as adding a line to your `Gemfile`

can be installed with `gem install american_date`

```
➜  ~  irb                      
2.0.0p0 :001 > require 'american_date'
=> true 
2.0.0p0 :002 > Date.parse('11/02/2013')
=> #<Date: 2013-11-02 ((2456599j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

Answer (score 1):

Typically you want to store and send data to ruby in the format `YYYY-MM-DD`, i.e 2013-09-01

```
Date.parse("2013-09-01")
# => Sun, 01 Sep 2013
```

I usually use the `altField` property of jquery datepicker. altField should reference a hidden field you add to the page to store the YYYY-MM-DD format of the date, then in ruby you would ignore the value sent from the datepicker input field.

- http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-altField
- http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-altFormat

Example: Given rails model Event with attribute start_on

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  // initialize the datepicker input field
  jQuery('#date_picker_start_on').datepicker({
    "altField":"#event_start_on",
    "altFormat":"yy-mm-dd",
    "dateFormat":"m/d/yy"
  }); 

  // this is need to work around a defect in datepicker altField handling
  jQuery('#date_picker_start_on').change(function() { 
    if (!$(this).val()) { 
      // clear the hidden field if datepicker cleared          
      jQuery('#event_start_on').val(''); 
    } 
  });

});

// assuming the markup of the hidden field something like
<input id="event_start_on" name="event[start_on]" type="hidden" />
```

NOTE that the altFormat of yy-mm-dd on the datepicker translates to YYYY-MM-DD - http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate

You would need to set the `dateFormat` to the proper format for the logged on users locale

Comment: Thanks this is a great answer. And I have been down this route. I have a lot of date fields and it soon became a mess. I think I'll go with the american_date gem.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`Date::strptime`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-strptime), you can specify date format.

```
Date.parse("11/02/2013")
# => #<Date: 2013-02-11 ((2456335j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
Date.strptime("11/02/2013", '%m/%d/%Y')
# => #<Date: 2013-11-02 ((2456599j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

Comment: Thanks! The problem is not how to get the right date format, but rather making js and rouby talk together. When the user enters 11.02.2013, I want both js and ruby to understand it as 11 feb 2013 and when the users enters 11/02/2013 is should be entered as 2 Now 2013.

Comment: @AndreasLyngstad do you want js or ruby guess the correct time format? May be you can use regex?